# Remove Last 2 folders from a directory path string column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, charindex

I have files written to table from both Linux and Windows

Here are the expectations:
Remove the file name and the last directory if it has any numbers

- 'E:\OP\data\SQLSERVER\FA\09_18_2023\TEST095126.AF' Will look like this 'E:\OP\data\SQLSERVER\FA'
- 'E:\PTDATA\Os_040722_or.af' will look like this 'E:\PTDATA'
- 'E:\RXD\RXD_OR.AF' will look like this 'E:\RXD'
- '/op_opps/PM/Arc/TS1X2/CLM/20190801/DYH1.AF' will look like this   '/op_opps/PM/Arc/TS1X2/CLM'
- '/op_opps/rxd/rxdmprd_rxdm_o.af' will look like this '/op_opps/rxd'
- '/op_opps/PM/Arc/ACVRS/CLP/201905/TMOS.CMPDYH1.AF' will look like this '/op_opps/PM/Arc/ACVRS/CLP'

Here is some temp data to play with

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (DIRECTORY NVARCHAR(150) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('E:\OP\data\SQLSERVER\FA\09_18_2023\TEST095126.AF')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('E:\ORS\ordsplprd.af')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('E:\PPT\PPN_ARCHIVE.af')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('E:\test_upgrade.af')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('E:\RXD\RXD_OR.AF')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('E:\SQLSERVER\ARO_050522_PM.AF')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('E:\PTDATA\Os_040722_or.af')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('E:\sql\Or_05May22_00011.af')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('/op_opps/PM/Arc/TS1X2/CLM/20190801/DYH1.AF')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('/op_opps/PM/Arc/TS1X2/CLM/20190801/GLT1.AF')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('/op_opps/PM/Arc/CRS/CLP/201706/PMHS.CAPCHP1.AF')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('/op_opps/PM/Arc/TS1X2/CLM/201908/RESEARC1.AF')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('/op_opps/PM/Arc/ACCRS/CLP/201701/PMHS.CAPCHS1.AF')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('/op_opps/rxd/rxdmprd_rxdm_o.af')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('/op_opps/PM/Arc/ACVRS/CLP/201905/TMOS.CMPDYH1.AF')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (DIRECTORY) VALUES ('/op_opps/DIR/08_10_2023/XMDYCERT145203.AF')
```

This is my starting query

```sql
SELECT LEFT(DIRECTORY,LEN(DIRECTORY)-CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(DIRECTORY))+1)
FROM #TEMP
```

Here is where I have gotten so far but I'm not sure how to get this logic to also apply this to windows directory's and I am not sure how to remove the last file if it has any numbers in it

I don't care so much if it has a / or \ at the end as long as the actual file name and dated path is removed

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? This can be accomplished in several ways, some of which are more elegant in newer versions.